# bundle.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined using a JavaScript (ES6) object

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined
    at j (bundle.js:1)
    at v (bundle.js:1)
    at new target (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
    at bundle.js:1
```

Using the following script

```
<script>
let sel_selector = rms.createSelector(id="traj_selector", collections=["trajectories"], single={ single: false });
</script>

<main>
    <div>
    <h3>Select</h3>
    <div id="traj_selector"></div>
    </div>
</main>
```

The JavaScript (ES6) object, rms, acts as a interface between RMS and your JavaScript plugin scripts. The global variable, rms, provides an RMS JavaScript API.

How can I define the arguments to rsm.createSelector in order to for the Svelte compiler to define them so the runtime error does not happen?

Comment: your script tag is wrong, you cant use named arguments, just remove `id=` `single=` and `collections=`

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the named arguments, but the I get a new error

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at Object.rms.createSelector (<anonymous>:726:9)
    at j (bundle.js:1)
    at v (bundle.js:1)
    at new target (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
    at bundle.js:1

Comment: '''rms.createSelector = function (id, collections, config = {}) {
    let single_select = ('single' in config) ? config['single'] : false;
    let create_elements = ('create_elements' in config) ? config['create_elements'] : true;
    let e = document.getElementById(id);

    if (create_elements) {
      e.classList.add('rms-selector');
      e.classList.add('rms-selector-button');
      e.innerHTML = '<img class="rms-selector-icon"><span class="rms-selector-label"></span><span class="rms-selector-chevron">&#x25BC;</span>';
    }'''

Comment: From what you posted, this means `e` is null, meaning `document.getElementById(id)` returned null. This is probably because your function call fires before the div with `id="traj_selector"` is mounted to the DOM. Wrap your function call inside Svelte's `onMount` helper to fix this, see: https://svelte.dev/docs#onMount

Comment: Thanks, it works now. The fix was to remove the named arguments and put the function inside the onMount.